# Presenting a login with storyboards for iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, storyboard

I have a simple iOS Master-Detail Application
-> On the iPad it's a splitview, on the iPhone it's a simply a tableview with navigation

Now I need to have a login first but I just can't find a proper solution for it.

I think the only part of the application that should decide whether a login needs to be presented is the AppDelegate.
But how would I have to wire my storyboard to be able to do that on both.. iPhone and iPad?

The other idea is to start with the login and dismiss it if it's not needed any more. But I also can't push or modal present a splitview on the iPad...

How would you solve this problem?
Without storyboards it's easy.. but with storyboards for me it seems hard do to... but I have to admit that I don't have any storyboards experience so far...

Thanks for helping

Comment: Georg -- Paks gave you a terrific answer. Can you please mark it as answered for him?

Comment: Of course! I completely forgot... Thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://maybelost.com/2011/12/tutorial-storyboard-app-with-core-data/

Download this sample app. It contains a Login with CoreData. Its very simple :)

Several weeks ago i used that also for my first Login and it worked like charm.

Hope it will help you too!

Comment: @Paks the link appears to be broken